# How to use a external trigger to stop structured streaming query?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark structured streaming and I want to check if a `stop` file exists to exit my program.

I can do something like:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val query = SparkSession...load.writeStream.foreachBatch{
      if (stop file exist) exit(0)
      // do some processing here
    }.start()
    // add Execute Listener here to listen query
    query.awaitTermination()
}
```

However, this could only be triggered if there are new rows appended to this query table. If there are no new rows, the `stop` file would have no impact whatsoever.

Any better idea to implement this trigger?

---

Above is the question, thanks to the accepted answer below, here is my code that finally works well.

```
object QueryManager {
  def queryTerminator(query: StreamingQuery): Runnable = new Runnable {
    override def run() = {if(stop condition) query.stop()}
  }
  def listenTermination(query: StreamingQuery) = {
    Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
      queryTerminator(query), initialDelay=1, delay=1, SECONDS
    )
  }
}
// and in main method
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val query = SparkSession...load.writeStream.foreachBatch{      
      // do some processing here
    }.start()
    // add Execute Listener here to listen query
    QueryManager.listenTermination(query)

    query.awaitTermination()


    // I am not familar with scala, 
    // but it seems would not exit if we do not add this
    System.exit(0) 
}
```

Please let me know if there is any wrong about it.

Comment: Do you still need `if (stop file exist) exit(0)` inside `foreachBatch`? This `System.exit(0)` is most likely due to the `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor` that uses a non-daemon thread and hence blocks the main thread to exit. Since you're after `query.awaitTermination()`, the `query` is indeed terminated.

Comment: my fault..just copied and pasted the above code, I am updating it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Any better idea to implement this trigger?

A streaming query is a separate daemon thread of a Structured Streaming application. It runs forever until it is stopped using [StreamingQuery.stop](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery).

There are at least two ways to access a running streaming query:

1. [DataStreamWriter.start()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter)
2. [StreamingQueryManager](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager)

The idea is to have a "control thread" in your Structured Streaming application that would listen to stop requests (with the ID of the streaming query or queries) and simply execute `stop` on the running streaming queries.

---

Think of a Spark Structured Streaming application as a single-JVM application with multiple threads. You can have one more to control the threads. That's the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
val query = df.writeStream.format("console").start()   // get the query object

query.id          // get the unique identifier of the running query that persists across restarts from checkpoint data

query.runId       // get the unique id of this run of the query, which will be generated at every start/restart

query.name        // get the name of the auto-generated or user-specified name

query.explain()   // print detailed explanations of the query

query.stop()      // stop the query

query.awaitTermination()   // block until query is terminated, with stop() or with error

query.exception       // the exception if the query has been terminated with error

query.recentProgress  // an array of the most recent progress updates for this query

query.lastProgress    // the most recent progress update of this streaming query
```

Ref: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#managing-streaming-queries

A simple spark-shell demo:

```scala
scala> val text = spark.readStream.format("socket").option("host", "localhost").option("port", 9999).load
22/04/09 16:40:00 WARN TextSocketSourceProvider: The socket source should not be used for production applications! It does not support recovery.
text: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string]

scala> val words = text.as[String].flatMap(_.split(" "))
words: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]

scala> val counts = words.groupBy("value").count
counts: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: string, count: bigint]

scala> val writer = counts.writeStream.queryName("NetworkWordCounts").outputMode("update").format("console").option("truncate", false)
writer: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter@57167840

scala> val query = writer.start
22/04/09 16:42:15 WARN ResolveWriteToStream: Temporary checkpoint location created which is deleted normally when the query didn't fail: /tmp/temporary-55e06380-a953-4fb4-8af1-6a3fa6b40a4f. If it's required to delete it under any circumstances, please set spark.sql.streaming.forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation to true. Important to know deleting temp checkpoint folder is best effort.
22/04/09 16:42:15 WARN ResolveWriteToStream: spark.sql.adaptive.enabled is not supported in streaming DataFrames/Datasets and will be disabled.
query: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery = org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryWrapper@5bf7053d

-------------------------------------------
Batch: 0
-------------------------------------------
+-----+-----+
|value|count|
+-----+-----+
+-----+-----+

scala> query.status
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryStatus =
{
  "message" : "Waiting for data to arrive",
  "isDataAvailable" : false,
  "isTriggerActive" : false
}

scala> query.id
res1: java.util.UUID = e58ea08a-a251-47a9-a148-2f9660c41120

scala> query.name
res2: String = NetworkWordCounts

scala> spark.streams
res3: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager = org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager@2bb09d00

scala> spark.streams.active.foreach(q => println(q.id, q.name))
(e58ea08a-a251-47a9-a148-2f9660c41120,NetworkWordCounts)

scala> spark.streams.get(query.id)
res8: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery = org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryWrapper@5bf7053d

scala> spark.streams.get(query.id).stop

scala> spark.streams.get(query.id).status
java.lang.NullPointerException
  ... 47 elided

scala> query.status
res11: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryStatus =
{
  "message" : "Stopped",
  "isDataAvailable" : false,
  "isTriggerActive" : false
}

scala>
```